# AWS's CloudFront : how requests are redirected the Edge locations

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

I read many articles about CloudFront and Edge Locations.

I can't understand how the user's request is automatically routed to his nearest edge location ?
Can someone explains exactly what happens when a client requests a static resource ? what are the network components (ISP, AWS, etc.) are called ?

Regards.

Answer (score 4):

from AWS docs (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/CloudFrontRegionaledgecaches.html?shortFooter=true)

> When a viewer makes a request by your website or application, DNS
>   routes the request to the CloudFront edge location that can best serve
>   the user’s request. This location is typically the nearest CloudFront
>   edge location in terms of latency

"latency" means the time it takes to get a request to and from the CloudFront edge location.  It's not the same as "bandwidth", it's more like a reaction time

For details of how AWS monitors latency, see the Route53 documentation

If the edge location doesn't have a particular item that is requested then it will query a near neighbour...

> If the files are in the cache, CloudFront returns them to the user. If
>   the files are not in the cache, the edge servers go to the nearest
>   Regional Edge Cache to fetch the object. In the Regional Edge Cache
>   location, CloudFront again checks its cache for the requested files.

If that doesn't work then the file is requested from the "origin server" which is the original web server or S3 bucket that contains the master copy of the site.

UPDATE:  Just to add what @michael-sqlbot says below.  Cloudfront access for the enduser happens via a "distribution domain name".  This is a domain name in the form "abc123.mycloudfront.net".  This name must be in Route53.  It is possible to use a CNAME from your own DNS registered domains to indirect to this name

When the "distribution domain name" is queried in @michael-sqlbot's words

> the DNS query results in the browser receiving an answer including IP
>   addresses that are selected in order to route the request to the
>   CloudFront edge location that can best serve the user’s request.

To put it slightly differently, the same "distribution domain name" is used worldwide.  But in different locations, this maps to different IP addresses.  The IP addresses are "typically" the nearest by a latency measure but presumably, this is not absolutely guaranteed to be the case

Comment: But how DNS routes the request to the CloudFront edge location ? And which DNS ist it ? ISP's ? Route53's ?

Comment: cloudfront defines domain name "end points" which can have SSL bound to them and which always are attached to Route53.   Route53 has latency based routing as a feature.  That's my understanding of how that bit of the puzzle works.  If anyone knows any different I'd be interested to hear about it!

Comment: The answer you get when you look up the IP address of a CloudFront distribution varies by your IP address (if detectable via EDNS0) and otherwise by your ISP's resolver's IP address, using an internal geolocation/latency database in Route 53, which provides DNS resolution of CloudFront destinations whether or not your domain is hosted in Route 53.   The DNS request does not route to the edge location -- the DNS *answer* provides IP addresses that are located at the CloudFront edge that Route 53 has selected as most appropriate (optimal/lowest latency) based on your IP range.

Comment: The quote from the docs would be (perhaps) clearer if it was phrased like this: "When a viewer makes a request by your website or application, *the* DNS *query results in the browser receiving an answer including IP addresses that are selected in order to* route the request to the CloudFront edge location that can best serve the user’s request." (my additions in italics)

Comment: How does geo serving of IP addresses work with DNS services such as google's 8.8.8.8 or cloudflare's 1.1.1.1 that are used by people all over the world? Wouldn't google/cloudflare add the IP addresses to their cache of the first user to visit a domain and then everyone in the world would get served those same A records regardless of location?

Comment: I would imagine that 8.8.8.8 is an AnyCast address https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anycast

Answer (score -1):

When a browser makes a request for www.example.com, it first has to do a DNS lookup to establish the IP address of the server to send the HTTP request. Its at this point the DNS server decides which edge location IP address to route your request. The returned IP address is selected based on your IP address, so your always routed to a geographically local edge location.

When an edge location receives your HTTP request, it will either return a cached response (if available), otherwise it will make a request back to the origin, then return this response to the browser and optionally keep a copy (based on the headers sent from the origin/cloudfront config)

FYI technically this is not a redirection - that is a feature of HTTP, and can only happen after you have gotten the IP address of the server.

Comment: This is partially correct. The key to determining the closest edge location is by Amazon DNS using anycast. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anycast

Comment: How the ISP's DNS server knows about Edge Locations ?

Comment: @JohnHanley a nearby authoritative Route 53 DNS server (not edge location) is reached via Anycast. That server returns an answer (for the nearest CloudFront edge location) that differs based on your IP address or your ISP's DNS resolver's IP address, as dictated by Route 53's internal geolocation database.